# データのグループ化について

Tags: python

以下のデータで送信元IP,宛先ポート,TCP/UDPが同じである場合はグループ化し、グループ後のデータ件数を表示させたい。

```
csv_data = '''
送信元IP,宛先IP,宛先ポート,TCP/UDP,送信セグメント,宛先セグメント
1.1.1.1,7.7.7.7,80,TCP,大阪,京都
3.3.3.3,7.7.7.8,15000,UDP,京都,大阪
4.4.4.4,7.7.7.9,18000,UDP,東京,京都
1.1.1.1,7.7.7.3,80,TCP,大阪,福岡
6.6.6.6,7.7.7.4,22,TCP,福岡,千葉
1.1.1.1,7.7.7.5,80,UDP,東京,大阪
'''
```

期待する出力結果

```
output = '''
データ件数,送信元IP,宛先IP,宛先ポート,TCP/UDP,送信セグメント,宛先セグメント
1,1.1.1.1,7.7.7.7,80,TCP,大阪,京都
1,1.1.1.1,7.7.7.3,80,TCP,大阪,福岡
2,1.1.1.1,7.7.7.5,80,UDP,東京,大阪
3,3.3.3.3,7.7.7.8,15000,UDP,京都,大阪
4,4.4.4.4,7.7.7.9,18000,UDP,東京,京都
5,6.6.6.6,7.7.7.4,22,TCP,福岡,千葉
'''
```

これまでに試したこと
以下のコードを実行しましたが、宛先IP、送信セグメント、宛先セグメントが結合されて表示されてしまいます。

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))
df2=df.groupby(["送信元IP","宛先ポート","TCP/UDP"],as_index=True)["宛先IP","セグメント","宛先セグメント"].sum().reset_index()
```

データの件数に関しては、グループ化した結果のdf2をto_excelでエクセルに出力してからマニュアルで作成していますが、エクセルに出力する前にデータ件数を作成できる方法などございましたら、ご教示ください。

Comment: 「期待する出力結果」を見ると、やりたい事は”送信元IP,宛先ポート,TCP/UDPでデータをソートしたい”で良いでしょうか？

Comment: データをソートし、送信元IP、宛先ポート、TCP/UDPが同じであれば、そのグループの件数をカウントしたいが実現したいことです。

Comment: つまり「期待する出力結果」は本当に欲しい結果ではないということでしょうか？欲しい結果のデータフレームを質問に追記されると回答しやすくなるかと思います。ソートについてもソートの優先順位やソート順を明記されると良いかと思います。

Comment: 送信元IP,宛先ポート,TCP/UDPが同じでほかが異なる場合はどう表示しますか?

Comment: いいえ。出力結果の通りで、送信元、宛先ポート、TCP/UDPが一致している場合は、同じデータとしてカウントするため、データ件数は増えず、その他では件数が増えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> グループ後のデータ件数

グループ毎のデータ件数を集計すると以下の様な結果になりますが、提示されている「期待する処理結果」とは異なります。もしかして、「データ件数」ではなく「グループ番号」ではないでしょうか？

```py
cols = ['送信元IP', '宛先ポート', 'TCP/UDP']
df = df.sort_values(cols)
df.insert(loc = 0, column = 'データ件数',
          value = df.groupby(cols)[cols[0]].transform('count'))

print(df)
```

| データ件数 | 送信元IP | 宛先IP | 宛先ポート | TCP/UDP | 送信セグメント | 宛先セグメント |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.1.1.1 | 7.7.7.7 | 80 | TCP | 大阪 | 京都 |
| 2 | 1.1.1.1 | 7.7.7.3 | 80 | TCP | 大阪 | 福岡 |
| 1 | 1.1.1.1 | 7.7.7.5 | 80 | UDP | 東京 | 大阪 |
| 1 | 3.3.3.3 | 7.7.7.8 | 15000 | UDP | 京都 | 大阪 |
| 1 | 4.4.4.4 | 7.7.7.9 | 18000 | UDP | 東京 | 京都 |
| 1 | 6.6.6.6 | 7.7.7.4 | 22 | TCP | 福岡 | 千葉 |

**追記**

「データ件数」ではなく「グループ番号」の場合は以下の様にします。

```py
cols = ['送信元IP', '宛先ポート', 'TCP/UDP']
df = df.sort_values(cols).reset_index(drop=True)
df.insert(loc=0, column='グループ番号', value=df.groupby(cols).ngroup()+1)

print(df)
```

| グループ番号 | 送信元IP | 宛先IP | 宛先ポート | TCP/UDP | 送信セグメント | 宛先セグメント |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1.1.1 | 7.7.7.7 | 80 | TCP | 大阪 | 京都 |
| 1 | 1.1.1.1 | 7.7.7.3 | 80 | TCP | 大阪 | 福岡 |
| 2 | 1.1.1.1 | 7.7.7.5 | 80 | UDP | 東京 | 大阪 |
| 3 | 3.3.3.3 | 7.7.7.8 | 15000 | UDP | 京都 | 大阪 |
| 4 | 4.4.4.4 | 7.7.7.9 | 18000 | UDP | 東京 | 京都 |
| 5 | 6.6.6.6 | 7.7.7.4 | 22 | TCP | 福岡 | 千葉 |

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、グループ番号が欲しい出力結果となります。お手数ですが、value=df.groupby(cols).ngroup()+1)の部分が分からないので、教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: `ngroup()` は `groupby()` で分けた各グループに連番を振ります。連番は `0` から始まりますので、`+1` をすることで `1` から始まる様にしています。

Comment: ご説明ありがとうございます。

Comment: すみません、2点教えてください。1. colの順番を変えることによって出力結果は変わるでしょうか。2. 出力結果でグループ番号が1から始まらないケースがあるのですが、なぜでしょうか。

Comment: 1. について、ソートの順序が変わりますので、出力結果が変わる場合があります。2. については具体例がないと何とも言えません。

Comment: すみません。ではNaN値が入る理由は何か分かりますでしょうか？

Comment: 送信元IP, 宛先ポート, TCP/UDP のいずれか(もしくは複数) が、空欄になっていることが考えられます。動作確認はしていませんが、`df.insert(loc=0, column='グループ番号', value=df.groupby(cols, dropna=False).ngroup()+1)` とするとよいかもしれません。

Comment: すみません。頂いたコードでは正しく集計できませんでした。お手数をおかけしました。